# Change order of array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have some code in Wordpress that gets the images that are attached to a specific post.
It puts all the information of that post in to an array then pulls the images from it using the built in Wordpress function `wp_get_attachment_image`

I then use a `foreach` loop to display the images in an image slider.
The problem I have is that it is putting 'image1' in position 1 of the array, and 'image2' in position 0 of the array. 
So it's displaying image 2 first.

here's my code.

```
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'attachment',
      'numberposts' => -1,
      'post_status' => null,
      'post_parent' => $post->ID
     );

    $attachments = get_posts( $args );          
    $images = array($attachments);
    echo '<div id="postSlider"><div class="slides_container">';
    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        echo '<div>' . wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'large') . '</div>';
        }

        echo '</div>';
        if(sizeof($attachments) > 1) {
            echo '<div class="sliderControls">
            <a href="#" class="sliderBtnPrev">Previous</a>
            <a href="#" class="sliderBtnNext">Next</a>
            <span class="sliderPagination">1 of 3</span>
            </div>';
        }
    }   
    echo '</div>';
```

From what I've read the `foreach` loop will preserve the order of the array. So, I'm thinking I need to change the order of the array so that the loop sees 'image1' (array position [1]) first.

My knowledge of arrays is limited and so I'm not sure how to do this.. any help appreciated.

Comment: @AdvaitAmin, please refrain from creating [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) like `array-functions` in the future.

Comment: @Charles not understand much, can you explain briefly in your words???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the order programmatically, have a look at the various [array sorting functions in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php), especially

- `uasort()`— Sort an array with a user-defined comparison function and maintain index association
- `uksort()`— Sort an array by keys using a user-defined comparison function
- `usort()`— Sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function

but for wordpress checkout this http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: Thanks for the link to `get_posts`
That gave me the info i need

Answer (score 0):

If the you want to show the image maes in sorted order use `sort` just before the foreach

```
    sort($attachments);
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    echo '<div>' . wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'large') . '</div>';
    }
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: @PrashanthBendra yes bro you good in array & its functions...may be your answer in always in 5 min...heads off...